# <%= @request.query.inspect %> brings up undefined method `query' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

hey guys I'm doing this lesson by schneems
https://github.com/Stephenitis/ruby_view_server (see readme)

I get to step 6) Talking to your Server, i'm meant to add  <%= @request.query.inspect %>

when I run $ ruby page_generator_with_layout.rb

**I get this error**

```
  - Converting .html.erb to html with Layout !!!
(erb):14:in `process_erb': undefined method `query' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Jupitor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
    from /Users/Jupitor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `result'
    from page_generator_with_layout.rb:6:in `process_erb'
    from page_generator_with_layout.rb:24:in `block in <main>'
    from page_generator_with_layout.rb:13:in `each'
    from page_generator_with_layout.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What about you remove the `@` before `request` ?

Comment: it still gives me the error message.

Comment: Oh sorry I read a bit too fast what you wrote. It is written you*'re building the html from the server we have access to the request*. Are you really sending a request to the server? If no, your request is should be nil.

Comment: You're getting the error because `@request` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run $ ruby page_generator_with_layout.rb anymore, as the server is looking directly at the view (.html.erb file), but not .html;
(Correct me if I'm wrong, as I am doing this exercise myself right now, and made the same mistake earlier)